# XSD schema for Liberty server.xml

Tags: java, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am using Liberty application server, which have server.xml as a configuration file for server.

Is there a XSD schema for server.xml?

Any of schemes for open-liberty or websphere-liberty - would be good for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can generate one using the 'serverSchemaGen' script from the Liberty 'bin' directory.

```
./serverSchemaGen server1
```

The server will need to be started and the 'localConnector-1.0' feature needs to be enabled. It will generate a schema that is specific to that server (ie, it will only generate content for features that are enabled on that server.)

Alternatively, you can run:

```
java -jar wlp/bin/tools/ws-schemagen.jar {output file}
```

This will generate a complete schema using all available features.

Answer (score 1):

The things allowed in server.xml depend on which features are used. There isn't a published schema which includes everything, but liberty does include tools for creating an xml schema for your setup.

You can generate a schema for all the features you have installed by running

`java -jar wlp/bin/tools/ws-schemagen.jar output.xsd`

Alternatively, you can generate a schema for the features enabled for a particular server with the following steps:

1. Add `localConnector-1.0` to the list of features in the `server.xml`
2. Start the server
3. Run `wlp/bin/serverSchemaGen myServerName`